# How do I get my computer's microphone working at the press of a button? -- Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently working on a project for Udacity. (Side note: they're not entirely helpful.) In the project, you must hit the record button, then hit the stop button. Then you are taken to a second screen where you should be able to press various buttons to playback your voice. My app won't playback my voice.

I get this error, which may or may not be relevant:

```
2020-04-23 18:33:04.071824-0700 PitchPerfect[8222:13398558] [plugin] 
AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600002752c20> 
F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
```

The one thing I did do was add the microphone to info.plist:

[image]

I restarted Xcode and Simulator. No luck.

I'm using Xcode 11.4.1. Here is the relevant code (it relies on another file):

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

   // MARK: Outlets

   @IBOutlet weak var snailButton: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var chipmunkButton: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var rabbitButton: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var vaderButton: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var echoButton: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var reverbButton: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!

   var recordedAudioURL: URL!
   var audioFile:AVAudioFile!
   var audioEngine:AVAudioEngine!
   var audioPlayerNode: AVAudioPlayerNode!
   var stopTimer: Timer!

   enum ButtonType: Int {
       case slow = 0, fast, chipmunk, vader, echo, reverb
   }

   // MARK: Actions

   @IBAction func playSoundForButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch(ButtonType(rawValue: sender.tag)!) {
    case .slow:
        playSound(rate: 0.5)
    case .fast:
        playSound(rate: 1.5)
    case .chipmunk:
        playSound(pitch: 1000)
    case .vader:
        playSound(pitch: -1000)
    case .echo:
        playSound(echo: true)
    case .reverb:
        playSound(reverb: true)
    }

    configureUI(.playing)
}

@IBAction func stopButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    stopAudio()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupAudio()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    configureUI(.notPlaying)
}

}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: I tap it, and nothing happens.

Comment: I've put in a breakpoint. How do I watch the code path?

Comment: I got this: ""UIApp is nil which means we cannot dispatch control actions to their targets. If this assert is hit, we probably got here without UIApplicationMain() being executed, which likely means this code is not running in an app (perhaps a unit test being run without a host app) and will not work as expected.""

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that the problem is this expression:

```
AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath!, settings: [:])
```

You won't get far with no settings for your recording. So you are playing silence.

Comment: Ah, I see it. What are the options for the setting?

Comment: That would be telling. Research is your business.